# ¿Quitar la clave y valor "id" en todos los objetos de un array de objetos en JS?

Tags: javascript, objeto

Hola a todos muchas gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios, estoy extrayendo los valores de un array de objetos donde cada valor de cada clave lo paso a un array el motivo de mi pregunta es el siguiente quiero eliminar la clave id de todos mis objetos antes de pasarlos a mí array tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
const dataObject = [
  {id: 1, producto: 'Jabon', precio: 90, Marca: 'Escudo'},
  {id: 2, producto: 'Cloro', precio: 25, Marca: 'Cloralex'},
  {id: 3, producto: 'Margarina', precio: 12, Marca: 'Artua'}
];
```

Quiero eliminar la clave id de todos estos objetos, esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```js
const dataObject = [
  {id: 1, producto: 'Jabon', precio: 90, Marca: 'Escudo'},
  {id: 2, producto: 'Cloro', precio: 25, Marca: 'Cloralex'},
  {id: 3, producto: 'Margarina', precio: 12, Marca: 'Artua'}
];

const dataArray = new Array();

dataObject.forEach((obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      dataArray.push(obj[key])
  }
})

console.log(dataArray)
```

Sin embargo en este código sigo conservando el ID por lo cual en la salida de mi nuevo array estoy almacenando el valor de ID y es lo que no quiero. Gracias de ante mano por sus respuestas.

Comment: La función map genera un arreglo ejecutando una función con cada uno de los elementos de otro array. Parece que lo estás usando como si se tratara de un forEach.

Comment: Tienes razón amigo, exclente corrijo entonces, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si queres evitar pasarlo, entonces no lo pases.. si ves esa key, usa el if, y no la pases...

```js
const dataObject = [
  {id: 1, producto: 'Jabon', precio: 90, Marca: 'Escudo'},
  {id: 2, producto: 'Cloro', precio: 25, Marca: 'Cloralex'},
  {id: 3, producto: 'Margarina', precio: 12, Marca: 'Artua'}
];

const dataArray = new Array();

dataObject.forEach((obj) => {
    for (const key in obj) {
      if (key != "id")
      {
        dataArray.push(obj[key])
       }
  }
})

console.log(dataArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo más simple que puedes hacer es usar `delete` con el elemento que quieres borrar.

```
dataObject.forEach(el => delete el.id)
```

Comment: Para mi esta respuesta responde exactamente al título de la pregunta formulada.